Use of \tikz@lib@parse@join@by doesn't match its definition
I'm having the following error message:
! Use of \tikz@lib@parse@join@by doesn't match its definition.
<argument> r
            ound
l.137                       \draw [join=round,black,dotted]
                                               ($(closeWait.north west) + (-...

This is my code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}  %%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,chains,automata,shapes,matrix,positioning,scopes,calc,quotes,backgrounds,babel}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} %

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Préambule}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

      %
      % Styles for states, and state edges
      %
      \tikzstyle{state} = [draw, very thick, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=7em, node distance=8em, font={\sffamily\bfseries}]
      \tikzstyle{stateEdgePortion} = [black,thick];
      \tikzstyle{stateEdge} = [stateEdgePortion,->];
      \tikzstyle{edgeLabel} = [pos=0.5, text centered, font={\sffamily\small}];

      %
      % Position States
      %
      \node[state, name=closedStart] {CLOSED};
      \node[state, name=listen, below of=closedStart] {LISTEN};
      \node[state, name=synSent, below of=listen, right of=listen, xshift=8em] {SYN\_SENT};
      \node[state, name=synRcvd, below of=listen, left of=listen, xshift=-8em] {SYN\_RCVD};
      \node[state, name=established, below of=listen, node distance=14em] {ESTABLISHED};
      \node[state, name=finWait1, below of=established, left of=established, node distance=7em, xshift=-9em] {FIN\_WAIT\_1};
      \node[state, name=finWait2, below of=finWait1] {FIN\_WAIT\_2};
      \node[state, name=closeWait, below of=established, right of=established, node distance=7em, xshift=9em] {CLOSE\_WAIT};
      \node[state, name=closing, below of=established, node distance=14em] {CLOSING};
      \node[state, name=lastAck, below of=closeWait] {LAST\_ACK};
      \node[state, name=timeWait, below of=closing] {TIME\_WAIT};

      %
      % Connect States via edges
      %
      \draw ($(closedStart.south) + (-.5em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-3em]{\emph{Passive open}} 
          ($(listen.north) + (-.5em,0)$); 
      \draw ($(listen.north) + (.5em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, xshift=2em]{\emph{Close}} 
          ($(closedStart.south) + (.5em,0)$);

      \draw ($(listen.south) + (-1em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend left=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-2em, yshift=1em]{SYN/SYN + ACK} 
          ($(synRcvd.east) + (0,1em)$);
      \draw ($(listen.south) + (1em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend right=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=1em, yshift=1em]{\emph{Send}/SYN} 
          ($(synSent.west) + (0,1em)$);

      \draw ($(synRcvd.north) + (.5em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend left=45] node[edgeLabel,xshift=-4em]{\emph{Timeout}/RST} 
          ($(closedStart.west) + (0,-.5em)$);

      \draw ($(synSent.north) + (-.5em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend right=45] node[edgeLabel,xshift=-1em, yshift=-1em]{\emph{Close}} 
          ($(closedStart.east) + (0,-.5em)$);
      \draw ($(closedStart.east) + (0,.5em)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend left=45] node[edgeLabel,xshift=4em]{\emph{Active open}/SYN} 
          ($(synSent.north) + (.5em,0)$);

      \draw (synSent.west) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, yshift=1em]{SYN/SYN + ACK} 
          (synRcvd.east);
      \draw (synRcvd) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-2.5em]{\emph{Close}/FIN} 
          (finWait1);

      \draw ($(synRcvd.east) + (0,-1em)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend left=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-1em, yshift=-1em]{ACK} 
          ($(established.north) + (-1em,0)$);
      \draw ($(synSent.west) + (0,-1em)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend right=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=3em, yshift=-1em]{SYN + ACK/ACK} 
          ($(established.north) + (1em,0)$);

      \draw ($(established.south) + (-1em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend left=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-1em, yshift=1em]{\emph{Close}/FIN} 
          ($(finWait1.east) + (0,.5em)$);
      \draw ($(established.south) + (1em,0)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend right=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=1em, yshift=1em]{FIN/ACK} 
          ($(closeWait.west) + (0,1em)$);

      \draw (finWait1.south) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-2em]{ACK} 
          (finWait2.north);
      \draw ($(finWait1.east) + (0,-.5em)$) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend left=22.5] node[edgeLabel, yshift=1em]{ACK} 
          (closing.north);
      \draw (finWait1.south east) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, xshift=1em, yshift=2em, text width=3em]{FIN + ACK/ACK} 
          (timeWait.north west);

      \draw (finWait2.south) 
          edge[stateEdge, bend right=22.5] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-2em, yshift=-1em]{FIN/ACK} 
          (timeWait.west);

      \draw (closing) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel, xshift=-2em]{ACK} 
          (timeWait);

      \draw (closeWait) 
          edge[stateEdge] node[edgeLabel,xshift=2.5em]{\emph{Close}/FIN} 
          (lastAck);

      %
      % Connect lastAck to closed is slightly more complicated
      % no direct line-of-sight, so we need to take the scenic route
      %
      \coordinate (lastAck2ClosedA) at ($(lastAck.east) + (2em,0)$);
      \coordinate (lastAck2ClosedB) at ($(closedStart.north -| lastAck.east) + (2em,1em)$);
      \coordinate (lastAck2ClosedC) at ($(closedStart.north) + (0.5em,1em)$);
      \draw (lastAck.east) edge[stateEdgePortion] (lastAck2ClosedA);
      \draw (lastAck2ClosedA) edge[stateEdgePortion] node[edgeLabel,xshift=-1.5em, yshift=-4em]{ACK} (lastAck2ClosedB);
      \draw (lastAck2ClosedB) edge[stateEdgePortion] (lastAck2ClosedC);
      \draw (lastAck2ClosedC) edge[stateEdge] ($(closedStart.north) + (0.5em,0)$);

      %
      % likewise for timeWait to closed
      %
      \coordinate (timeWait2ClosedA) at ($(timeWait.south) + (0,-1em)$);
      \coordinate (timeWait2ClosedB) at ($(timeWait.south -| finWait2.west) + (-2em,-1em)$);
      \coordinate (timeWait2ClosedC) at ($(closedStart.north -| finWait2.west) + (-2em,1em)$);
      \coordinate (timeWait2ClosedD) at ($(closedStart.north) + (-0.5em,1em)$);
      \draw (timeWait.south) edge[stateEdgePortion] (timeWait2ClosedA);
      \draw (timeWait2ClosedA) edge[stateEdgePortion] (timeWait2ClosedB);
      \draw (timeWait2ClosedB) edge[stateEdgePortion] (timeWait2ClosedC);
      \draw (timeWait2ClosedC) edge[stateEdgePortion] 
        node[edgeLabel, text width=12.25em, yshift=1.5em]{\emph{Timeout after two maximum segment lifetimes (2*MSL)}} 
        (timeWait2ClosedD);
      \draw (timeWait2ClosedD) edge[stateEdge] ($(closedStart.north) + (-0.5em,0)$);

      % draw dotted lines around passive and active closes
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw [join=round,black,dotted] ($(closeWait.north west) + (-1em, -1em)$) rectangle ($(lastAck.south east) + (1em, 1em)$);
        \draw [join=round,black,dotted] ($(finWait1.north west) + (-1em, -1em)$) rectangle ($(timeWait.south east) + (1em, 1em)$);
      \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


you need to provide a minimal example of the error. i.e. we need code which produces that error when we compile it so we can reproduce the problem.

just a guess, but I suspect the issue is in your use of mdframed. you have done something like e.g. start an environment without closing it, start a command without finishing it or used a feature in a strange unsupported way. that is, I'm guessing your content is going into boxes you never actually typeset because they never get finished. note the complaint from mdframed about improper splitting. but since you've provided no code which causes the problem, this is just a guess.

@cfr, Error message and code updated.

the join=round is causing the error. you need to type line join=round

Maybe what you intended was line join=round. The join=with ⟨with⟩ by ⟨options⟩ is a different key provided by chains library and expects a specific pattern as its value, thus causing a parsing error.

Both cap and join are still part of TikZ as deprecated/legacy code. As your whole MWE is full of old deprecated code, the addition of the newer chains library clashes with it. Follow @muzimuzhiZ's explanations and also replace \tikzstyle with \tikzset and below of with below=of from the positioning library while you're at it.

that appears to be a completely different error than the one you originally asked about?

Thank you all. @muzimuzhi Z solution didn't help to fix the error. I will give up on that.

@cProg Really? After replacing all two occurrences of join=round with line join=round, your example compiles without error on my side. The overfull box messages are another thing. Do you still get the same error, or encountered new error(s)? Which version of tikz is loaded (add \listoffiles in preamble and check out the end of log)?
